# Lower limit of acceleration in newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Recently I came across an [article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2007/apr/25/new-lower-limit-set-for-newtons-law) which says there is a lower limit of acceleration of the order of $10^{-10}ms^{-2}$. Can any one tell me if it is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article tells you, that experimentally a new limit of $5 \cdot 10^{-14}\, \mathrm{m/s^2}$ has been established:

> By observing a torsion pendulum oscillating with a very long period, physicists in the US have now found that the law is valid down to accelerations of about $5 \cdot 10^{-14}\, \mathrm{m/s^2}$ – a thousand times smaller than the previous lower limit.

The limit of $10^{-10}\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ was a theoretical threshold that comes from a group of theories called [MOND (modified newtonian dynamics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOND) in which the relation $F = ma$ breaks down for very small accelerations. These models where put forward as an alternative to the hypothesis of dark matter to explain the rotation curve of galaxies, other observations might also be explained by MOND (e.g. the Pioneer anomaly – which by now is thought to be caused by thermal radiation).

In conclusion, the article you link says that in the described experiment the linear relation between force and accelerations holds down to a limit far below the limit necessary for MOND scenarios explaining the rotation curve of galaxies (and the threshold occurs to fit this observational data). This suggests MOND is experimentally falsified in the current form if these experimental results can be reproduced (which increases the credibility of the dark matter hypothesis).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true, as you would see if you read the article. It's talking about a lower limit on the *range of validity* of Newton's second law - in other words, the experiment described in the article has confirmed that $F = ma$ even when $a$ is as small as $5\times 10^{-14}\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

It is *not* saying that there is a minimum value (a lower limit) of acceleration.